# Why is fluid font sizes not working for font-size?

Tags: html, css, web

I am new at web development so I come up with lots of problems. The one I am facing now is font size not set to fluid. I copied the code from youtube but I am not getting the same results as the YouTuber. Apparently, the text is supposed to change size as the width of the window changes. Please have a look at the code and attached images to understand the situation more precisely.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  --header1: calc(2rem+1vw);
  --header2: calc(3.5rem+1vw);
  --header3: calc(3rem+1vw);
  --header4: calc(2.4rem+1vw);
  --text: calc(1.5rem+1vw);
  --big: calc(2.4rem+1vw);
  --special-color: #906272;
  --background-color: #414141;
  --gray-text: #525252;
}
body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}
h1 {
  font-size: var(--header1);
}
li,
button,
label,
input,
p {
  font-size: calc (1rem + 1vw);
  /* font-size: var(--text); */
}
h2 {
  font-size: var(--header1);
}
h3 {
  font-size: var(--header3);
  font-weight: normal;
}
h4,
h5 {
  font-size: var(--header4);
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"  />
 
<h1>This is h1</h1>
<h2>This is h2</h2>
<h3>This is h3</h3>
<h4>This is h4</h4>
<h5>This is h5</h5>
<h6>This is h6</h6>
<p>
  This is p<br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
  Cum eos quidem sunt cumque. Eos aut sunt provident ratione quia in commodi
  nam harum, nihil soluta praesentium facilis error dolorum similique quos
  quas quam cupiditate odio pariatur animi, odit quod at mollitia? Facere
  laborum maiores illum culpa earum voluptatibus reprehenderit impedit.
</p>
```

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

css calc need some spaces...

```css
body {
  font-family : "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size   : 62.5%;
  --header1   : calc( 2rem   + 1vw );
  --header2   : calc( 3.5rem + 1vw );
  --header3   : calc( 3rem   + 1vw );
  --header4   : calc( 2.4rem + 1vw );
  --text      : calc( 1.5rem + 1vw );
  --big       : calc( 2.4rem + 1vw );
  }
h1 { font-size : var(--header1); }
h2 { font-size : var(--header1); }
h3 {
  font-size   : var(--header3);
  font-weight : normal;
  }
h4, h5 {
  font-size : var(--header4);
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"  />
 
<h1>This is h1</h1>
<h2>This is h2</h2>
<h3>This is h3</h3>
<h4>This is h4</h4>
<h5>This is h5</h5>
<h6>This is h6</h6>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This worked (after adding space ONLY to +)

Comment: @Huzaifa ;-) this is true, but i think when you finish reading thousands of css lines you will end up putting the same kind of spaces that i use

Answer (score 0):

You made a typo. There should be no space between calc and the parentheses:

```
p {
  font-size: calc (1rem + 1vw);  
}
```

Should be:

```
p {
  font-size: calc(1rem + 1vw);  
}
```

Also when using calc() there should be a space between the '+' and the values.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
  --header1: calc(2rem + 1vw);
  --header2: calc(3.5rem + 1vw);
  --header3: calc(3rem + 1vw);
  --header4: calc(2.4rem + 1vw);
  --text: calc(1.5rem + 1vw);
  --big: calc(2.4rem + 1vw);
  --special-color: #906272;
  --background-color: #414141;
  --gray-text: #525252;
}
body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}
h1 {
  font-size: var(--header1);
}
li,
button,
label,
input,
p {
  font-size: calc(1rem + 1vw);
  /* font-size: var(--text); */
}
h2 {
  font-size: var(--header1);
}
h3 {
  font-size: var(--header3);
  font-weight: normal;
}
h4,
h5 {
  font-size: var(--header4);
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"  />
 
<h1>This is h1</h1>
<h2>This is h2</h2>
<h3>This is h3</h3>
<h4>This is h4</h4>
<h5>This is h5</h5>
<h6>This is h6</h6>
<p>
  This is p<br />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
  Cum eos quidem sunt cumque. Eos aut sunt provident ratione quia in commodi
  nam harum, nihil soluta praesentium facilis error dolorum similique quos
  quas quam cupiditate odio pariatur animi, odit quod at mollitia? Facere
  laborum maiores illum culpa earum voluptatibus reprehenderit impedit.
</p>
```

Comment: Hate when this happens... Thanks a million

Comment: It happens to the best of us :) you're welcome